# PriorityQueue returning incorrect ordering for custom comparator?

Tags: java

I combine a priority level(from 0 to 3) with user ID and use a comparator to sort the priority queue.
The main function and comparator are as below

```
public class PriQueTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Comparator<String> comparator = new StringPriComparator();
    PriorityQueue<String> queue = 
        new PriorityQueue<String>(3, comparator);
    queue.add("3"+"128763711");
    queue.add("2"+"128763712");
    queue.add("0"+"128763718");
    queue.add("1"+"128763713");
    queue.add("3"+"128763714");
    queue.add("2"+"128763715");
    queue.add("2"+"128763716");
    queue.add("3"+"128763717");

    while (queue.size() != 0)
    {
        System.out.println( (queue.remove().substring(1)));
    }

  }
  public static class StringPriComparator implements Comparator<String>
  {
    @Override
    public int compare(String x, String y)
    {
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) >  Integer.parseInt(y.substring(0, 1)))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) <  Integer.parseInt(y.substring(0, 1)))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;

     }
  }


}
```

Sorting of priorities is correct but the sorting of users within the same priority level is not correct

The output of above code is

```
128763711
128763714
128763717
128763716
128763712
128763715
128763713
128763718
```

where as the expected output is as follows

```
128763711
128763714
128763717
128763712*
128763715*
128763716*
128763713
128763718
```

Here user with id 128763712 made the request with priority 2 before user with id 128763716
Any ideas if something not correct or Is my comparator wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your comparator only looks at the first digit, which is working correctly.  Since you don't do anything further in the comparator with the rest of the value, you get whatever ordering is in the priority queue for anything where the first digit is equal.

You need 2 more cases in your comparator where, after the first two checks, you compare the remaining parts of the values and return the right value if the first value is less than or greater than the second.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The remaining part of the string is the user ID and I actually dont need to sort them on their ID but on the order in which they requested. Here user with id  128763712 made the request with priority 2 before user with id 128763716

Comment: A priority queue is not required to preserve insert order; that is why the comparator is involved.  A priority queue is not a queue in the FIFO sense; all determinations about what item is at the top of the queue is controlled by the comparator.  (Priority queues are often implemented as binary trees, which will not preserve insert order.)  If you need preserved insert order, you perhaps need a different data structure, perhaps a dictionary/map (with priority as the key) with an array or list as the second parameter, holding the items in insert order.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change this comparator:

```
public static class StringPriComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String x, String y) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) > Integer.parseInt(y.substring(0, 1))) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, 1)) < Integer.parseInt(y.substring(0, 1))) {
            return 1;
        }
        return x.substring(1).compareTo(y.substring(1));
    }
}
```

If the priority levels are the same, then use natural order to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works correct. Your queue sequentially gives items with priority 3, 2, and 1. Inside same priority items are unsorted.

Comment: within the same priority level i need the users to be sorted in order they made the request. Here user with id  128763712 made the request with priority 2 before user with id 128763716

Comment: Use another prefix (or sufix) to designate order of request like `queue.add("3"+appendLeadingZeroesTo5Digits(id++)+"128763711")` and sort using it (here - first 6 digits);